# Can I link C# coded UI tests into test manager without an associated manual test?

Tags: c#, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

We have 1000's of coded UI automated test cases written that are not associated with a manual test case.  We need sexy pass/fail metrics from these automated test cases.  I think getting these pass/fail metrics into TFS (somehow) is probably the best solution... but I don't want to write a manual test case for every single automated test.

Is there a way I can get these metrics to TFS?  for example:

- Can I automatically Generate stub test cases in MTM based on method
  names of the existing tests?  ... and then link the automated TCs to
  those stubs?

Answer (score 1):

i think what you want can be done by directly importing the test methods to TFS as test case and then can be added to MTM. Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff942471.aspx) link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you propose via some custom coding and the TFS API.  But there is no way to do that without custom coding as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ordered test containing all your Coded UI tests and then automate the single test case with this ordered test.
You can also organize your Coded UI test into several ordered tests and create a "main" ordered test containing them all (and automate the single test case with the "main" ordered test).
But you will still have to add new created Coded UI tests to the ordered test manually.
If you want to automate this, too, you can code against TFS API in order to add single tests to the ordered test automatically (e.g. during a build) based on tests' names or categories.